# Example of a field embedding from K to K which is not an Automorphism.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

A field embedding from K to K is an injective homomorphism. What is an example of a field embedding which is not surjective (and therefore not an automorphism)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a field $K$ and consider $K(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$, the field of rational functions in countably infinite variables with coefficients in $K$ (equivalently, a transcendental field extension of $K$ with countably infinite transcendence degree, and no non-trivial algebraic elements).

Now consider the embedding
$$
K(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\to K(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\\
1\mapsto 1\\
x_i\mapsto x_{i+1}
$$